# Javascript get text from input and copy it to a span

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a template for a copy and paste it have a input and I want to put some text in it and press a button that says update and copy the text from the input to somewhere in the template

My attempt:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Donovan_D Minecraft - Youtube Description 
Template</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--Start Template-->
<div>===================================<br>
My Channel:<br>
https://youtube.com/c/DonovanDMinecraft<br>
===================================<br>
Twitch:<br>
http://twitch.tv/donovan_dmc<br>
Twitter:<br>
http://twitter.com/Donovan_DMC<br>
===================================<br>
Sub2Janabell:<br>
https://youtube.com/channel/UC0NTNba35ADUstIoLm
YLiiA<br>
===================================<br>
My <span style="text-decoration:underline;"  id="v">1.9,
1.10, 1.11</span> Skyblock/Guilds Server:<br>
IP: play.mcpsb.co<br>
Server store:<br>
http://store.mcpsb.co<br>
Server Website:<br>
https://www.mcpsb.co<br>
===================================<br>
Thanks for <span style="text-decoration:underline;"
id="sub">970</span> Subscribers! make sure to like,
comment, subscribe, and Stay Awesome!
===================================<br>
<!--End Template-->
<hr>
NOT PART OF TEMPLATE<br>
</div>
<b>Version:</b><br>
Change: <input id="vr"><br>
<button onclick="ver()">Update Version</button><br>
<hr>
<b>Subscriber Count:</b><br>
Change: <input id="cs"><br>
<button onclick="csub()">Update Subscriber
   Count</button><br>
<hr>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ver() {
document.getElementById("v").textContent =
document.getElementById("vr").value;
}
function csub() {
document.getElementById("sub").textContent =
document.getElementById("cs").value;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[I'm trying to do it twice]

Am I doing somthing wrong here?

Solved, one more thing, is there a way to see if the input is the same as is in the span or if the input is empty? And I only want numbers used in them... is there a way to block other characters/replace themy once they are typed?

Aswell for the subscriber Ammount I want to get live numbers from akshatmittal.com or some other live counts service for youtube Subscribers. Is there a way to get the live Subscriber Count without php, ajax or anything besides javascript and html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get the data out of your text boxes with `.innerHTML`. Form-field values need to be gotten with `.value`.

Additionally, if the data being typed into the text boxes will not contain any HTML that needs to be parsed, you should use `.textContent` to set that data into  your `<span>`s instead of `.innerHTML` since there isn't any HTML.

**`.value`** is for getting/setting form-field values (checkboxes, radio buttons, text boxes, etc.) or attribute values.

**`.innerHTML`** is for getting/setting non-form-field element content that will contain HTML markup. When using this to set content, any HTML in the value being set will be parsed by the browser.

**`.textContent`** is for getting/setting non-form-field element content that will not contain HTML markup. HTML markup will be ignored. `.textContent` is the better choice when no HTML will be gotten/set because it performs better than `.innerHTML` (doesn't have to parse anything).

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Donovan_D Minecraft - Youtube Description Template</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>To View HTML Click <a href="code.txt">Here </a></h3><br>
  <!--Start Template-->
  <div>===================================<br>
    My Channel:<br>
    https://youtube.com/c/DonovanDMinecraft<br>
    ===================================<br>
    Twitch:<br>
    http://twitch.tv/donovan_dmc<br>
    Twitter:<br>
    http://twitter.com/Donovan_DMC<br>
    ===================================<br>
    Sub2Janabell:<br>
    https://youtube.com/channel/UC0NTNba35ADUstIoLmYLiiA<br>
    ===================================<br>
    My <span style="text-decoration:underline;" id="v">1.9, 1.10, 1.11</span> Skyblock/Guilds Server:<br>
    IP: play.mcpsb.co<br>
    Server store:<br>
    http://store.mcpsb.co<br>
    Server Website:<br>
    https://www.mcpsb.co<br>
    ===================================<br>
    Thanks for <span style="text-decoration:underline;" id="sub">970</span> Subscribers! make sure to like, comment, subscribe, and Stay Awesome!
     ===================================<br>
    <!--End Template-->
    <hr>
    NOT PART OF TEMPLATE<br>
  </div>
  <b>Version:</b><br>
  Change: <input id="vr"><br>
  <button onclick="ver()">Update Version</button><br>
  <hr>
  <b>Subscriber Count:</b><br>
  Change: <input id="cs"><br>
  <button onclick="csub()">Update Subscriber Count</button><br>
  <hr>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Get/set form-field values using the .value property
    // Get/set non-form-field values with either .textContent or .innerHTML

    function ver() {
      document.getElementById("v").textContent = document.getElementById("vr").value;
    }
    
    function csub() {
      document.getElementById("sub").textContent = document.getElementById("cs").value;
    }
  </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following script changes to get the input value and change the textContent of the target element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ver() {

document.getElementById("v").textContent = document.getElementById("vr").value;
}
function csub() {
document.getElementById("sub").textContent = document.getElementById("cs").value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: How is this any different than my answer?

Comment: @Scott and now you have your points seeing as you did much more work...

Comment: @Scott sorry didn't see your answer when posting, brevity isn't a bad thing